# Python - Formatting output of most_common

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, counter

```
classement=Counter(results)
liste = classement.most_common()
print(liste)
```

Now what I have with the above print is

```
[(u'a', 5), (u'b', 3), (u'c', 2), (u'd', 2), (u'e', 2), (u'f', 2), (u'g', 2), (u'h', 1), (u'i', 1)]
```

But I would like something like that, I don't know how to format it

```
a = 5
b = 3
c = 2
etc...
etc...
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just printing your list you can iterate through it printing each key and its value like this:

```
for key, val in liste:
    print(key, '=', val)
```

Comment: It's better but not what I want... look [here](http://prntscr.com/h0z3ds)

Answer (score 1):

With `str.format()` function:

```
for k,v in liste:
    print('{} = {}'.format(k,v))
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(liste)` will print the entire list. But you need to iterate through each element in the list. You can do it as

```
for key,val in liste:
        print('{} = {}'.format(key,val))
```

Since each element in the `liste` corresponds to a **tuple**,the statement `key,val in liste` will unpack the tuple and you can print them however you want it.